# Rmagick gem unable to set format

Tags: ruby, rubygems, homebrew, rmagick

My environment is 10.9.2 and it seems I am unable to load

```
imagemagick/6.8.7-7/lib/ImageMagick//modules-Q16/coders/png.la
```

and this comes up when trying to set format on an image

```
thumb = Magick::Image.read("img.jpg").first

thumb.format = "PNG"
```

`brew doctor` suggested `brew update` but to no avail.

Has anyone experienced this or knows why this might be happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last comment in this related GitHub issue seems to recommend brewing from source.

```
brew install imagemagick --build-from-source
```